# Web-base IDE with shell / file management integration for *nix

Tags: linux, web-applications, unix, ide

is there anything like a web application (like in php) that exposes access to the files on the server it's installed on, shell access and integrated IDE?

I know it's not something secure, but for development purposes it would be useful when you have a *nix dev server you can't directly access (like, you're behind a proxy and can only navigate *:80).

I know of various administration tools a-la [Webadmin](http://www.webmin.com/) or [cPanel](http://www.cpanel.net/), but they lack any sort of web-based IDE to edit the files (as long as i know).

Maybe [Mozilla Skywriter](https://mozillalabs.com/skywriter/) (ex Project Bespin) is similar to what I'm after, but I'm not sure about its current state (considering that they're in the process of rewriting it) and most of all i think it lacks server-side integration.

Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: I think it's an excellent business idea. Never heard of such thing, but will certainly take a look at said skywriter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [ShiftEdit](http://shiftedit.net/) or CodeRun?

Both are web-based HTML/CSS/JS/PHP editor with some decent IDE features (snippets, syntax debugging).  I believe both are SaaS, so no hosting it on your own machine.

You might also be interested in ECCO, which is open-source, so you can self-host it.

Answer (score 0):

[Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) has a file manager; you can also create custom commands to allow edition of particular files in user by user case.

> **File Manager**: View, edit and change permissions on files and directories on your system with a Windows-like file manager. All operating systems.

It uses https by default and can be as secure as any other remote access tool like SSH, for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Linux client, or can get an X11 environment through something like Cygwin, I would suggest using X11 forwarding over SSH. Once you get it set up it's as easy as

```
ssh -X user@server
```

From there on out, you could start Eclipse, or any other IDE/Editor from the command line.

I haven't seen any server-installable online IDE's, but there are a number of them if you don't mind hosting your code on their servers. Coderun has one, Ideone is another.

You might want to check out this tersely-explained SF project: http://online-ide.sourceforge.net/. It looks to be like a first-attempt at what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple answer to your question. Depending on the web server, there may be a whole spectrum of options available to you but in general web servers are quite strict about exposing their internal environment/code for obvious reasons.

At my work place, we ran into a similar situation with restricted access to our production server. Our work around was to create a password protected upload service which simply overwrote the files we wanted to modify from local copies on our machines. Whilst we didn't install any in-place editing system, it could easily be done, via CodeMirror (http://codemirror.net/) and some ajax calls.

It goes without saying that the viability of this approach is dependent on your administrative right to configure the uploading behaviour of the target web server.

Answer (score 0):

Typically command line access to development servers is via ssh.  There are various Windows ssh clients, most notably putty.  There are also ssh tunnels which can run over http.

The capabilities of an ssh solution are significantly greater that would be available to a web server application.

Remote graphical access is often done using VNC, and more recently RDP.  Alertatively, a local Xserver can be be used to supply a display for applications running the development server.

These applications can provide the ability to edit files for which it is very insecure to allow a web application write access.

The web applications, I have seen provide significantly less functionality than is available through the above choices.  In limited cases such as configuration files, the web application may provide a simpler interface to do standard changes.

Answer (score 0):

PHPShell is pretty cool, it just gives you, well... a shell.

http://phpshell.sourceforge.net/

can't use an "Integrated IDE" through it of course. But if you have a decent IDE then it should be able to access your remote files through SFTP and open/save them directly.

That said, I would recommend moving away from any host that is so limited as to not give you shell access, or find some way around the proxy using ssh tunnels.

Answer (score 0):

goormIDE has web-based shell and file explorer.

this looks like visual studio or eclipse

i think you need to try this~

- http://goorm.io
- http://github.com/xenoz0718/goorm

if you use node.js, just type this

```
$ npm install goorm -g
```